# making processRequest wait to another thread to end

Tags: multithreading, jsp, servlets, wait

I'm searching for a better solution for the following code,
I've a servlet that must process a request when the user presses one button, 
before to do anything I want my function to wait for another thread to ends what he's doing,
for now I'm using a simple session to do the thing:

```
boolean converted = (Boolean) request.getSession().getAttribute("converterthread");
        while(!converted){ // Wait
            converted = (Boolean) request.getSession().getAttribute("converterthread");
            }
```

When the thread ends his work it sets converterthread attribute of the session to true.
This all works fine, but I'm afraid that this is not the best solution, is asking for the session everytimes bad for the performance of the server?
I'm trying to use this.wait(1000) to making my function to check if the thread has ended every second, but I just get a monitor not found exception (or similar).

EDIT: In a different request method (that is called way before the upper one) I'm creating a thread that uses a xuggler class to do the conversion (so that the user doesn't wait for all the conversion to be ended).
Basically I create a new MyThread (extension of Runnable) and then I set my  "converterthread" attribute of the session to false

```
MyThread r = new MyThread(uploadedFile, fileDir, request.getSession());
request.getSession().setAttribute("converterthread", false);
```

After a while I create a thread with MyThread and I start it.
This is what MyThread looks like:

```
   public class MyThread implements Runnable {

        File uploadedFile;
        File fileDir;
        HttpSession session;
        boolean hasEnded = false;

        public MyThread(File f, File d, HttpSession s) {
            fileDir = d;
            uploadedFile = f;
            session = s;
        }

        public File returnFileDir()
        {
            return fileDir;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Converter(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath(), fileDir.getPath() + "\\video").run();
            //subito dopo voglio eliminare il file precedente
            uploadedFile.delete();  // è sicuro che termina per ultima la conversione
            //Aggiorno lo stato della sessione, sblocca il CutSave se aspettava la conversione
            session.setAttribute("converterthread", true);
            hasEnded = true;
            MyThreadQueue.get().removeThread(this);
            MyThreadQueue.get().runNextThread(); // se c'è un altro thread in attesa allora lo esegue
            //Il meccanismo garantisce un esecuzione dei thread in fila
        }
    }
```

As you can see, after the conversion I call session.setAttribute("converterthread", true);

Comment: what do you mean "I want another thread to end" ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: the tread is converting a file video, this takes long, I want to wait the conversion of the video (done in my other thread) before doing anything, I've done it already, I'm just asking if checking the state of the conversion by using request.getSession().getAttrubute("something") is a good thing to do

Comment: No, this is not right. If you can tell me how you are processing file video, I can suggest an easy way. You don't need to do multithreading when your app is container managed.

Comment: I've edited the question, I used multithreading just to make things faster for the user since I upload a video file and start to convert it all in the request method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a CountDownLatch, first put a countDownLatch in the session

```
session.setAttribute("latch",new CountDownLatch(1));
```

when the work is done, call

```
CountDownLatch latch=(CountDownLatch)session.getAttribute("latch");
latch.countDown();
```

then replace the while loop to:

```
CountDownLatch latch=(CoundDownLatch)session.getAttribute("latch");
latch.await(); // will wait for MyThread to call latch.countDown()
//also you can specify a timeout
//latch.await(2000) wait for 2 seconds
```

updated:

It's better not to pass the session into another thread, instead, you can directly pass the countDownLatch into MyThread instance

Comment: session is a constructor parameter of MyThread:) of course it is better to pass the countDownLatch to that thread instead of the HttpSession

Comment: yup, just noticed that. That's why deleted the comment. Anyway, that's not right approach while dealing with container managed components. check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You should not keep servlet waiting and dependent on a thread which is busy doing something else. That's not right.

**2)** If you really want to break up your multiple tasks then there is an easy way as below:

**>>** In your jsp/html page, create 2 `frames`.

**>>** In 1 of the frames, keep the button which user presses, which calls the servlet. And in the second frame, keep video processing servlet or whatever you want.

**>>** When user presses the button, the button will call the servlet through `javascript/ajax`. So once, servlet finishes its request, it will send the response back to the frame and append the response to the frame. And in the second frame, the update will happen the same way.